# Not able to install supervisor in CentOS 6.9 using easy_install nor pip

Tags: docker, pip, centos6, supervisord, easy-install

I am working in a Docker container which is being created from CentOS 6. This is basically how the `Dockerfile` looks like:

```
FROM centos:centos6
RUN yum update -y && \
    yum install -y epel-release && \
    yum install -y iproute python-setuptools hostname inotify-tools yum-utils which && \
    yum clean all && \
    easy_install supervisor
ADD container-files /
VOLUME ["/data"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/config/bootstrap.sh"]
```

When I run `docker build . -t test` for build and test the image it ends up with the following error:

```
...
Searching for supervisor
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/supervisor/
Couldn't find index page for 'supervisor' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or download links found for supervisor
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('supervisor')
```

I have tried also installing first pip and then install supervisor using pip as follow:

```
RUN yum update -y && \
    yum install -y epel-release && \
    yum install -y iproute python-setuptools hostname inotify-tools yum-utils which && \
    yum clean all && \
    easy_install pip && \
    pip install supervisor
```

And in this case it ends up with the following error:

```
Searching for pip
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
Couldn't find index page for 'pip' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or download links found for pip
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pip')
```

- I do have Internet connection
- I am not behind any firewall and/or proxy
- I do not have any AV since I am building the container from Fedora 27
- I do not have any IPTables and/or SELinux enabled
- Everything else does install properly the only thing failing is `supervisor`

I am missing something here? Is not supervisor supported by CentOS6? What's the right way to install this?

> Note: I could install directly from repos but the version is really old: `supervisor noarch 2.1-9.el6 epel` I am pretty sure I will be missing a lot of features

**UPDATE:**

After install `supervisor` using the recommended command `pip install supervisor` and try to start the container `docker run test` it doesn't work and I can see the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/supervisord", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2655, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 648, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 546, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: meld3>=0.6.5
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I tracked the error to easy_install. Check [Triying execute easy_install docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41028621/trying-to-execute-easy-install-or-pip-on-docker-build-says-command-not-found)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original problem  (with the `easy_install` solution) is that PyPi, the package repository, now requires `https://` connections.  `easy_install` simply doesn't know about this, so when it tries to contact http://pypi.python.org/simple/supervisor/ it gets:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 SSL is required
```

So `easy_install` simply won't work.

I'm not sure what's causing the error regarding the `meld3` package, but if you're using the EPEL repositories anyway you might as well just install the `python-meld` package:

```
FROM centos:centos6
RUN yum update -y && \
    yum install -y epel-release && \
    yum install -y \
      iproute \
      python-setuptools \
      hostname \
      inotify-tools \
      yum-utils \
      which \
      python-meld3 \
      python-pip && \
    yum clean all && \
    pip install supervisor
```

Answer (score 0):

I give you a working Dockerfile with the installation :

```
FROM centos:centos6
RUN yum update -y && \
    yum install -y epel-release && \
    yum install -y iproute python-setuptools hostname inotify-tools && \
    yum-utils which && \
    yum -y install python-pip && \
    yum clean all && \
    pip install supervisor
```

A workaround to the easy_install problem.

I hope this helps.

Comment: @ReynierPM It's working fine for me, but my image its just the generate with mi posted Dockerfile (i didn't check the rest of yours), anyways it seems its the mel3d version, or something related with the ENTRYPOINT i guess. Docker version 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6

Comment: I've tried and still not working I don't know what is happening, [here](https://github.com/reypm/centos6-supervisord) is the repository I have created for such container. Could you try that one?

Comment: I'll take a look and notice you here or by a PR on that repo.

Comment: @ReynierPM i just make a pull request to your repository, with some modifications to have python and the dependencies working, advices, but still not working (a failure from the supervisord.conf, dunno exactly). And a readme explaining some things.

Comment: cool I will take a look later at home but I get it to work easily with the solution provided in the other answer without the need to compile and/or install anything. Anyway both solutions are valid and I will merge your changes in a new branch so I can have both of the solutions working on my end